# Min-Heap tree bottom-up construction with duplicate values

Tags: data-structures, tree

I'm given the following values:

```
17 5 20 33 41 30 28 55 17 26 35 19 11 14 60
```

Using the bottom-up construction, I've found myself in a situation where I cannot decide which node to swap in this case. This happens specifically when percolating the value 60 downwards and swapping. At a point, it reaches here (portion of the tree):

```
 60
 / \
17 17
```

Now since we need to swap 60 with the smaller of the two child values, which one do I pick, left or right? My instinct tells me to pick the right child since the heaps are normally constructed Top-to-Bottom and sweep left to right since it calls for Heaps being Complete.

**note I could not tag this as homework due to insufficient rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, since the heap will come out fine no matter which one you pick.  I would pick the right, because it's a little faster on average due to the slightly lower average depth.